# Making Meteor method calls synchronous on the client

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor, synchronization, rxjs

I feel like I'm missing something. I was trying to tailor my product UI so that certain items are only displayed for admins. In addition, restricting access to certain "pages" in the router requires a synchronous call guard. I'd certainly prefer to keep things asynchronous, but that doesn't seem to meet the requirements.

In other environments, I'd create a boolean function like isAdmin() that checks user authorization/roles. But since users shouldn't see the implementation of the function for security reasons, it's best to use a server-only Meteor method. Although the method could be synchronous on the client (if no callback specified), the only way to get the return value is to use the asynchronous callback form of Meteor.call().

It seems like there are three ways to handle this, none of which are as simple as the boolean function:

1. Return an Observable from isAdmin(), but this pushes the issue out
   to wherever isAdmin() is called. It doesn't solve the router guard issue.
2. Do a Meteor.call() wherever isAdmin() is needed, discarding the
   isAdmin() function. This also pushes the problem to all the call
   sites, and doesn't address the router guard.
3. Don't return a value at all, but have the server-side method throw
   an exception if the user is not an admin. This, however, doesn't change the asynchronous nature of the method call.

I've seen examples using Meteor.wrapAsync or Future, but these use Fibers on the server, not the client.

Any other suggestions for other patterns, perhaps using rxjs? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

i think i'm not understanding your overall security strategy, but here are a couple things to think about.

security happens on the server, which it looks like you're well aware of.

in my current project, we use roles ([alanning:roles](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles)), and have several admin roles. these roles are published with the Meteor.user object, so on the client we can enable/disable links to pages by checking that.

so we agree that doing so isn't real security, because a user can simply navigate to that link or change their client Meteor.user object to expose that.

but on that page, we're probably going to be accessing admin-only data. since we handle the publish on the server, where we can check those admin roles for real, we can detect a non-admin user access and throw an error.

similarly, if we're publishing data to a user, and the items they get are based on roles, we can check that in the publish and publish only those items they're allowed to see. same idea with restricting fields on those published items.

to your question about "what does that client code look like that checks the roles?", it's really doing nothing more than querying the contents of the "roles" field on Meteor.user. so while it does give them a hint of what roles exist and how the app users them for visibility, imho it doesn't provide a path for mischief. so long as they can't access any restricted data, or successfully execute any restricted calls, it's secure.

so for each of our publishers and Meteor methods, we have tons of error checking, including roles (admin and otherwise). if anything doesn't line up, we throw an error.

Comment: Many good points Zim. I'd only add that making a sync call to the server for admin status can easily be circumvented in the debugger. The *layout* of the protected pages are included in the bundle that is sent up to the client, there's no solid way of hiding those. Preventing any *data* from being loaded into those layouts through server-side controls in publications is the normal pattern. There is also an alternative though, which is to separate out admin functions into a separate Meteor *application* tied to the same mongodb.

Comment: @MichelFloyd, yes, if it's important to protect the admin templates themselves, then either a separate app or module loading (which i've done in other frameworks but not Meteor) are good solutions. but can you say more about the debugger circumvention? i didn't follow.

Comment: Let's say the client makes a sync call to the server to decide whether or not to allow logic to proceed (using `.wrapAsync()` for example). Find that code in the debugger, set a breakpoint there in the client js debugger, wait for the value to return, then change it interactively so that it passes the test, continue on to the route.

Comment: @zim, thanks for the comments. Filtering published data appears to be the best approach, although I'm not yet convinced the publishing decision resides entirely on the server. The user requests certainly impact this, but maybe I just need to create more prototypes.

Comment: Some of my frustration in all this is we're also using alanning:roles. But whether it's my own errors or something else, checking roles on the client fails due to no data in the roles collection. I've added my own subscription to roles and tried other approaches. After spending a lot of time trying to get things to work (using Meteor1.5./Angular 4), I posted here.

Comment: One other point. Interesting idea about separating out the admin function to a separate app. I might be missing something, but it seems like this would only work if that app is not public; say, running on your corporate network rather than on a public-facing net. Access could also be restricted to a set of network addresses. In any other situation, you'd be facing the same access issues that I brought up.

Comment: for that roles package, they're published automatically with the Meteor.user object, you don't have to write your own publisher. e.g. on both client and server JS, you can run: Roles.userIsInRole(user, 'can-delete-users', 'admin')

Comment: The auto publish is what I would expect as well. However, when the client calls userIsInRole(), it ultimately does a Meteor.users.findOne(), which always returns undefined. Something is not working for me.

Comment: I'll add some code, but I expect some would see this as going off-topic. I will create a new question and point to it here.